# I don't understand association class - UML class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

[image]

I  don't yet completely seem to understand how association class works, why the role class attributes can't just be inside the person class?

as example:

### Person

- name
- position
- description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why the role class attributes can't just be inside the person class?

notice the multiplicity `1..*`, if you move *position* and *description* into *Person* you have to manage a collection of them and to associate each to the corresponding *Company*.

[from your remark]

For a given *Person* the *position* and *description* depends on each associated *Compagny*, so it is not possible to have the fields you propose except if *position* and *description* are both a collection, and to have a way/rule to know which entry in *position* and *description* correspond to the right *Compagny*.

Moving also these information in *Person* you remove the symmetry, it is also possible to move these information in *Compagny*, with the same remarks as for *Person*

An association class is both a class and a relation, when you implement it in a language like C++ or Java etc of course that concept does not exist, so one way is as you propose to move the fields in one of the two classes, or to create a third class having the expected fields more one to a *Person* and one to *Company*.

The advantage of the third class is to have all the associated information grouped having the equivalent of :

[image]

As example an object diagram can be :

[image]

Without the third class you need to know how to associate all the separated information, for instance having all in *Person* using three vectors to memorize the company and position and description you may use the same index value for all, but this is less clear and when you add/remove a *Company* for a *Person* you have to update all these vectors.

Comment: Can you elaborate more please? :)

Answer (score 7):

Suppose we live in a world where a person must have a role in a company in order to live and a company may exist without persons at all.

If that is all you want to know about the relationship between persons and companies, i.e. only the fact that there are such relationships and **nothing more**, you model it like this:

[image]

Then if you want **in addition** to capture  `position` and `description` of the `Person`'s **role** you use so called AssociationClass (`Role` in our case):

[image]

Each instance of `Role` has **four properties** (both an attribute and an end of an association are Properties in UML):

1. Company
2. Person
3. position
4. description

For example, suppose a person named *Scott Tiger* has roles in two companies - *Food Inc* and *Water Ltd* and each company knows that *Scott Tiger* has role in it. Then there will be two instances of `Role` (shown as tuples):

```
(Food Inc., Scott Tigger, eater, eats here)
(Water Inc., Scott Tigger, drinker, drinks here)
```

Now, returning to you question, it should be clear that an instance of `Person` with `name`, `position`, `description` attributes actually "lacks" `Company` and if you "add" an `Company` you will get `Role`, not `Person`!

So what you proposed in the end of your question is **a valid design, if you model `Company` and `Role` and a person is just an attribute of `Role`**:

[image]

It reads as follows: each instance of `Company` has zero or more `Role`s and each instance of `Role` has only one `Company`. Both ends of the association are navigable, i.e. `Role` knows its `Company` and `Company` knows its `Role`s.

[UML Specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/About-UML/) in clause **9.5.3** gives you the following advice:

> A Property may represent an *attribute* of a Classifier, a *memberEnd* of an Association, or in some cases both simultaneously.
>
> A useful convention for general modeling scenarios is that a Property whose type is a kind of Class is an Association
> end, while a property whose type is a kind of DataType is not. This convention is not enforced by UML.

Comment: nice answer, UV

Comment: Both ends of association have **unspecified** navigability.